# How to solve for a variable that is the base of an exponential and also a multiplicand on opposite sides of an equation?

Tags: exponential-function

The equation is $$KQ-Kq = nq^n$$
K is known and is a constant.  Q will be the independent variable if I can solve for q.  n is unknown, but may be considered as a constant and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  I would like to solve for q so I can calculate q as a function of Q for a given n.

Comment: You have an $n$th-degree polynomial equation in $q$. If $n=2$ it's rather easy, but for higher $n$ it gets unwieldy, and indeed finding an exact closed form for $q$ is impossible if $n>4$. I would use numerical root-finding techniques here.

Comment: @ PT: I was afraid of that.  Thank you for the explanation and suggestion.